# Are spices or produce required to be "glatt kosher"?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

At home, I have a jar of Pereg oregano that says "glatt kosher" and parve. Am I missing something? I thought "glatt" applies only to meat. If so, how can something be both fleishig and parve at the same time? Similarly, I've seen a store called "glatt farm". the store sells only produce. Does fruit have to be "glatt kosher"?

Comment: If it had bumps, they'd tell you you couldn't check it for bugs. :)

Comment: LOL! Etrogim have bumps and it's a fruit. Do they inspect them for bugs?

Comment: If you don't eat the skin, I don't think you need to check. CYLOR.

Comment: I saw a container of quinoa labeled [whole grain](http://www.edenfoods.com/store/popup_image.php?pID=106900&eID=j83ne81uhl43s9hoajbodqmef6). It just goes with the consumer ignorance rather than fighting it. Same here. People know they are supposed to prefer Glatt, without knowing why.

Answer (score 5):

Glatt meat means that the animal's lungs are completely smooth. The word "glatt" can not apply to produce, fish, poultry, and so on. ([MyJewishLearning](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/practices/Ritual/Kashrut_Dietary_Laws/Kosher_Food/Meat/Glatt_Kosher.shtml))

However, "in some instances it may be intended to imply that the product was processed under a superior hashgachah, as per the term's informal usage." ([Kashrut.com](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/glatt/))

Comment: Doesn't that mean that declaring the spices as both glatt and parve is misleading the consumer?

Comment: @DanF Only if you think the consumer will understand it in a different way than you intend. Same holds true for every claim by anyone ever.