# Is the use of the term "Glatt Kosher" a case of "Genivat Da'at"?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, business, fruits, vegetables

My understanding of the term "Glatt kosher" which I heard from 3 different mashgichim (kashrut supervisors)

The term "glatt" means "smooth" and applies only to beef and lamb. (I would assume that it applies to goat, venison and bison, but those items are less commonly obtainable in the U.S.)

It does not apply to poultry (chicken, turkey, duck). It does not apply to produce, spices, or dairy.

Given the last paragraph, several years ago, I saw a bottle of Pereg Oregano that had both a "glatt kosher" marking as well as saying "parve" - a contradiction, obviously. A produce store in my neighborhood is called "Glatt Farm", when they sell only produce.

One of the mashgichim explained that the term "glatt kosher" somehow came to mean "strictly kosher". In other words, it has been used as a marketing tool.

Glatt kosher products tend to cost more than regular kosher products. I am also aware of many people who don't understand the correct vs. "marketing" usage of this term, who go out of their way to find a store that sells only glatt kosher chickens and glatt kosher produce. This seems like a waste of money and time.

My question, isn't usage of this term a rather clear case of "Genivat Da'at" - taking advantage of someone's ignorance and misleading them.

I esp. question the usage of "glatt" on produce that's whole and uncut and it was farmed outside Israel, and does not need to be inspected for insects. What on earth (pun intended, here) could possibly make such produce more "strictly kosher" than "non-glatt" produce, and, again, why mislead someone into buying glatt kosher produce?

Comment: How exactly is someone being misled? Is a fresh apple (not grown in Israel) not kosher? I would think it is indeed kosher to the highest degree.

Comment: "that the term 'glatt kosher' somehow came to mean 'strictly kosher'" If that's what the term has come to mean then how can someone be misleading people by using it in the accepted manner?? This whole post just sounds like a forum for you to get annoyed at how a word is now used differently than it's original meaning. There's no real question here.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37916/are-spices-or-produce-required-to-be-glatt-kosher#comment100168_37917

Comment: If the term _Glatt_ has taken on a new meaning, how are you misleading people by using the new meaning? I could imagine an equally strong argument that saying something like "that apple is _not_ glatt kosher" is _geneivat daat_.

Comment: It's like saying "That pig is _treif_." It's probably not a _traifa_ (I'm not even sure that a non-kosher animal can even be called a _traifa_); that's just how people use the word now.

Comment: Do the people who don't understand the difference think it means "smooth" and only applies to beef et al? If not, what's the problem? If so, I say "lo plug" (plus they would know that _glatt_ isn't referring to what they think it means here). And if they don't know what it means, how is using the expression misleading?

Comment: @DanF I suggest this question be revised to say something more like "What is the modern meaning of 'glatt' kosher?," pointing out that it is not strictly confined to meat these days.

Comment: @SAH Thanks for your suggestion. At the moment, I'm not sure if that will do it for me. I have to mull it over. Your idea would be a completely different set of answersm and I think that given what I've already stated in my question, I know what the answer already is. It means "strictly" kosher. Perhaps, I may ask when or why did this defnition occur, and I think, here, too, the answer is that it was to make money.

Comment: @DanF Gotcha. I just think that question wouldn't be as downvoted ;)

Comment: @SAH I know that this site IS a "popularity contest", though, that's not what I'm seeking, here. Menachem's answer is pretty good.

Comment: @SAH Took part of your suggestion. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71689/5275. Thanks, again, for the idea. For now, I'm leaving this one, open, as well.

Comment: I only drink *glatt* kosher milk. If it's not smooth, it's probably spoiled. ;)

Comment: @Scimonster It's been a while since I've viewed this question. I'm not sure if it's *genivat da'at*, but, I can vouch for it sometimes being *gneivat mammon* (stealing money). There are stores that charge more for a product marked as "glatt" because of the notion that it has been made "more kosher" than a non-glatt product. But, I think if you're doing that on a product that can't be truly "glatt" (which as I said applies just to meat), what makes it "better kosher" than a different brand, when both brands have the same supervisory emblem?

Comment: @DanF I was being facetious, which I tried to indicate with the smiley. I don't actually use milk that says glatt. I was using the literal meaning of smooth, because non -smooth milk is probably spoiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not *Lifnei Iver*, as no one is being misled into committing a sin.  One could argue that it perhaps borders on false (or ignorant) marketing, when applied to products besides meat.

However, as the *mashgiach* you asked pointed out, the term has become synonymous with "strictly kosher, without question" (which is what is intended by saying that meat is *glatt*).  In this context, it is more of a "term of art" or a common borrowed expression rather than purely a marketing tool.

I do remember seeing ice cream advertised as *glatt kosher*... (Oy!)

Comment: I think this is a good answer. It's not _just_ a meaningless marketing word. Otherwise, everybody would advertise their food as glatt. Instead, the Israeli rabbanut has 3 levels of kashrut, just one of which is called glatt (at least in the English writing)

Comment: I think I've seen Glatt kosher internet service and smart phones, too. I also saw someone advertise a Glatt Kosher black hat. Of the above, the only one that the term "Glatt" makes sense is the hat, because some people **do** eat that :-)

Comment: Although it's not the original meaning as applied to _kashrus_, where it specifically referred to an animal's lungs, _glatt kosher_ could also mean plainly (i.e. unquestionably) kosher, from the general definition of the Yiddish word _glatt_.
Under this meaning, though, I'm afraid quite abit of _glatt kosher_ meat is not actually _glatt_ kosher - the _balei machshir_ don't tell you how many questions arose during the shechita and kashering process, only that the lungs were okay.

Comment: I think there is a point missing here - if something is marketed as "glatt" then ignorant people will assume that it is superior to non-"glatt" in some way and may feel that they are doing more of a mitzvah to buy the "glatt" one, or being more pious etc.  The implication is that non-"glatt" products don't have the best kashrus, and that's effectively loshon hara and perhaps that it is stealing from the non-"glatt" competitors, and from the consumer who is making a choice based on a lie?  Scott Adams gave a similar example in the Dilbert Future of cereal advertised as being "asbestos free".

Comment: @MosesSupposes Not missing the point. Marketing something as _glatt_ is an assertion — not an implication or unintended inference — that it is, in fact, superior in regards to its quality of _kashrus_. If that is untrue in a particular case, then it is indeed false marketing. But if it is true, it may indeed be more pious, be stealing neither from the customer nor from the competition, and no more _loshon hora_ than any advertisement that says or implies, "The other product is not as good as mine."

Comment: @Menachem that assumes that the competitors will all take the same approach if they have the same level of kashrus and label theirs as glatt too, which is unlikely to be true in many cases, especially since "glatt" is not well defined, and certainly not an absolute term when it isn't applied in its original meaning, so how can a manufacturer possibly be certain that their product has superior kashrus to a competitor?  They may even be unknowingly labelling theirs as "glatt" when a competitor with superior kashrus doesn't!